# Flutter App does not redirect to login screen after tapping logout

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crash, logout

I think I have deleted the data from Firestore and Firebase and that is why I'm getting redirected to home page instead of login page in flutter. And that is a code breakdown. Please help me to solve it. One more thing is that whenever I try to get to login page by clicking other buttons I get to home page only

I want to implement a logout function in flutter and if there is no data available show results according to that only. if the data is present logout the user and if not then show some error

Code to delete user data from the app:-

```
onPressed: ()async {
              try{
                if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null) {
                  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.delete();
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('NewUsers').doc(
                      docId).delete();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                      content: Text(
                        "Account Deleted Successfully",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )));
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                          LoginPage()));
                }
                else{
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                      content: Text(
                        "No Data Found to Delete",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )));
                }
              }
              on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
                Navigator.pop(context);
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                      content: Text(
                        "Sensitive Operation.Please Re-Authenticate",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )));
              }
            },
```

Code to logout user from app :-

```
InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        try {
                          if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null) {
                            HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
                            await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
                                content: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Logged Out from Account',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'CourierPrime',
                                          color: Colors.red,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    )),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white));
                          }
                          else {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                                content: Text(
                                  "Cannot Logout because no Data Found",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )));
                          }
                        }
                        on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
                          if (e.code=="permission-denied"){
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                content: Text(
                                  "The user does not have permission to execute the specified operation",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )));
                          }
                          else {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                content: Text(
                                  "Cannot Perform Operation. Re-try After short Period",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )));
                          }
                        }
                      }
```

Comment: Can you please provide also some code ?

Comment: I've added the conditions after getting the error, and I'm unable to logout from the app because all the data regarding the user is already deleted so it is redirecting me to the main page